# New data array of objects in D3 join is not being recognized correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

**Edit:** I think this is an interesting case of trying to bind data that changes to a D3 general update pattern, with a seemingly odd issue. I've done my best to create a great example that will help me and hopefully others understand this issue I'm running into...

I have spent ~30 minutes creating a reproducible example for this issue I am having with React and D3. Will bounty this post in 2 days as I need a solution on this, have spent a lot of time reading D3 docs, but haven't found a solution. Much of my next day will be spent trying to solve this.

I am attempting to use D3's general update pattern to create an interactive scatter plot. One of the important features of my web apps actual scatter plot is the ability to choose amongst 3 different datasets for the data for the scatter plot. At a high level, the data flow in my app is:

- a parent container loads three different datasets (example below uses 2 hardcoded data sets).
- a button group in the parent container selects the dataset of choice for the scatterplot.
- the parent container then renders a graph component that takes as a prop the selected dataset, and renders the graph.

In the example below, both dummy datasets have an `id` column, and in my actual data this is also the case amongst all 3 datasets. **However**, the keys vary between datasets (this is the point). The issue is as such (and is highlighted with console.logs()) - **Even though IT APPEARS (see console.log) as though the correct array of objects is being passed into the GraphApp component, it seems that the D3 general update pattern is not identifying the keys in the new `graphData` prop.**

The example below will highlight this issue better than my words above - I did my very best to keep the example as short as possible, although a certain minimum of code (2 components, a button group, a scatter plot) was needed:

```js
// AppGraph is responsible for drawing the scatterplot (of text names in this example)
class AppGraph extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
  }
  
  drawPoints() {
    const { graphData, graphType } = this.props;
    console.log('Data INSIDE of AppGraph component');
    console.log('graphData: ', graphData);
    console.log('graphType: ', graphType);

    const xShift = function(d) {
      if (graphType === "A") {
        return d.pts
      } else {
        return d.reb
      }
    }
    const yShift = function(d) {
      if (graphType === "A") {
        return d.ast
      } else {
        return d.blk
      }
    }
    
    // This is my general update pattern code
    // Likely something is wrong here, but i have been unable to pin the error
    const pointsLayer = d3.select('#my-svg').select('g.points')
    let groups = pointsLayer
      .selectAll(".myGroups")
      .data(graphData, d => d.id);

    const groupsExit = groups.exit().remove();
    const groupsEnter = groups.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "myGroups");

    groupsEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", d => xShift(d))
      .attr("cy", d => yShift(d));
      
    groups
      .selectAll("circle")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("cx", d => xShift(d))
      .attr("cy", d => yShift(d));

    groupsEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", d => xShift(d))
      .attr("y", d => yShift(d))
      .text(d => d.id);
      
    groups
      .selectAll("text")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("x", d => xShift(d))
      .attr("y", d => yShift(d))
      .text(d => d.id);

    groups = groupsEnter.merge(groups);
    groupsExit.remove()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    d3.select('#my-svg')
      .attr('width', '100%')
      .attr('height', '100%')
      .attr('viewBox', "0 0 " + (800) + " " + 600)
      .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMaxYMax")

    this.drawPoints();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.drawPoints()
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <svg id="my-svg">
        <g className="points" />
      </svg>
    )
  }  
}

// App is the Parent component that selects the correct dataset, and passes it into the Graph component
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      graphType: "A"
    }
  }

  handleButtonChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      graphType: event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {

    const { graphType } = this.state;

    // The two datasets to choose from
    const datasetA = [
      { id: 'tom', pts: 134, ast: 12 }, 
      { id: 'joe', pts: 224, ast: 114 },
      { id: 'bim', pts: 114, ast: 215 },
      { id: 'tim', pts: 243, ast: 16 },
      { id: 'nik', pts: 210, ast: 17 },
      { id: 'jib', pts: 312, ast: 287 }
    ];

    const datasetB = [
      { id: 'tom', reb: 115, blk: 32 }, 
      { id: 'joe', reb: 122, blk: 224 },
      { id: 'bim', reb: 211, blk: 55 },
      { id: 'tim', reb: 241, blk: 366 }
    ];
    
    // Radio button group determines the dataset passed to scatterplot
    const graphData = graphType === "A" ? datasetA : datasetB;

    // Render radio buttons and scatter plot
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div>
            <label>
              <input 
                type = {"radio"}
                value = {"A"}
                checked = {graphType === "A"}
                onChange = {this.handleButtonChange}
              /> 
              <span> {"A"} </span> 
            </label> 
          </div> 
          <div>
            <label>
              <input 
                type = {"radio"}
                value = {"B"}
                checked = {graphType === "B"}
                onChange = {this.handleButtonChange}
              /> 
              <span> {"B"} </span> 
            </label> 
          </div>
        </form>
        
        <AppGraph 
          graphType={graphType}
          graphData={graphData}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App /> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id='root'>
  Come On Work!
</div>
```

Please momentarily full screen the code demo so you can see the scatterplot in action without the console.logs() taking up the full window.

As you can see, the scatterplot breaks when toggling from `graphType` A to B. Even though the new `graphData` array is correctly passed into `AppGraph`, the x and y values are not observed on `graphData's` new keys (reb, and blk), and the scatterplot fails to update correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated here - very curious what I am doing wrong with regards to data flow / binding data in the general update pattern.

Edit: As a note, combining the 3 datasets into a single dataset would be **very burdensome** for a variety of reasons, and the current approach (updating `graphData` based on the radio buttons selected) is highly preferred.

**EDIT2**: I am beginning to suspect that the following line of code is not correct:

```
let groups = pointsLayer
  .selectAll(".myGroups")
  .data(graphData, d => d.id);
```

but i am not positive and have been unable so far to fix it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that [`selection.selectAll()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_selectAll) does not propagate data to the selected elements:

> The selected elements do not inherit data from this selection

Although you correctly bind the updated `graphData` to the groups, it is never passed on to the texts and circles, which still have the old data bound to them via the initial append. A way around this is to use [`selection.select()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_select) instead:

> Unlike [*selection*.selectAll](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_selectAll), *selection*.select *[…]* propagates data (if any) to selected children.

Putting this into your code makes it work like intended:

```js
// AppGraph is responsible for drawing the scatterplot (of text names in this example)
class AppGraph extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
  }
  
  drawPoints() {
    const { graphData, graphType } = this.props;
    console.log('Data INSIDE of AppGraph component');
    console.log('graphData: ', graphData);
    console.log('graphType: ', graphType);

    const xShift = d => graphType === "A" ? d.pts : d.reb;
    const yShift = d => graphType === "A" ? d.ast : d.blk;
    
    // This is my general update pattern code
    // Likely something is wrong here, but i have been unable to pin the error
    const pointsLayer = d3.select('#my-svg').select('g.points')
    let groups = pointsLayer
      .selectAll(".myGroups")
      .data(graphData, d => d.id);

    const groupsExit = groups.exit().remove();
    const groupsEnter = groups.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "myGroups");

    groupsEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", xShift)
      .attr("cy", yShift);
      
    groups
      .select("circle")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("cx", xShift)
      .attr("cy", yShift);

    groupsEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", xShift)
      .attr("y", yShift)
      .text(d => d.id);

    groups
      .select("text")
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("x", xShift)
      .attr("y", yShift)
      .text(d => d.id);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    d3.select('#my-svg')
      .attr('width', '100%')
      .attr('height', '100%')
      .attr('viewBox', "0 0 " + (800) + " " + 600)
      .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMaxYMax")

    this.drawPoints();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.drawPoints()
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <svg id="my-svg">
        <g className="points" />
      </svg>
    )
  }  
}

// App is the Parent component that selects the correct dataset, and passes it into the Graph component
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      graphType: "A"
    }
  }

  handleButtonChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      graphType: event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {

    const { graphType } = this.state;

    // The two datasets to choose from
    const datasetA = [
      { id: 'tom', pts: 134, ast: 12 }, 
      { id: 'joe', pts: 224, ast: 114 },
      { id: 'bim', pts: 114, ast: 215 },
      { id: 'tim', pts: 243, ast: 16 },
      { id: 'nik', pts: 210, ast: 17 },
      { id: 'jib', pts: 312, ast: 287 }
    ];

    const datasetB = [
      { id: 'tom', reb: 115, blk: 32 }, 
      { id: 'joe', reb: 122, blk: 224 },
      { id: 'bim', reb: 211, blk: 55 },
      { id: 'tim', reb: 241, blk: 366 }
    ];
    
    // Radio button group determines the dataset passed to scatterplot
    const graphData = graphType === "A" ? datasetA : datasetB;

    // Render radio buttons and scatter plot
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <div>
            <label>
              <input 
                type = {"radio"}
                value = {"A"}
                checked = {graphType === "A"}
                onChange = {this.handleButtonChange}
              /> 
              <span> {"A"} </span> 
            </label> 
          </div> 
          <div>
            <label>
              <input 
                type = {"radio"}
                value = {"B"}
                checked = {graphType === "B"}
                onChange = {this.handleButtonChange}
              /> 
              <span> {"B"} </span> 
            </label> 
          </div>
        </form>
        
        <AppGraph 
          graphType={graphType}
          graphData={graphData}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App /> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id='root'>
  Come On Work!
</div>
```

<sub>Aside: Although all the links in this answer refer to the latest version 5 the same holds true for version 4 which you are using.</sub>

Comment: If we replace `selectAll` with `select`, wouldn't it only select and transition only the first text element?

Comment: @Canovice Read the spec carefully: *"For each selected element, selects the first descendant element…"* Because you have a nested selection, i.e. groups where each contains a circle and a text, you can safely use `.select()`. This will select the first circle of each group or the text of the same.